# Testing the node app - request.agent not remembering the cookies

Tags: node.js, testing

I am trying to write test for my application. My issue is that the request.agent won't remember cookies. Here is my code:

```
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../../index.ts');
const agent = request.agent(app);
const {
  existingUser,
} = require('../fixtures/users');
const pool = require('../db');


let response;

afterEach(async () => {
  await app.close();
});


const authtests = () => {

  test('Should login existing user', async () => {
    await agent
          .post('/api/auth/login')
          .send({ 
            email: existingUser.email,
            password: existingUser.password
          })
          .expect(200)
          .then(response => {
            agent.jar.setCookie(response.headers['set-cookie'][0])
            // console.log('xxxxx', response.headers['set-cookie'][0])
          });



          response = await pool.query(`SELECT * FROM person`);
          if(response) {
            // console.log('===========================', response.rows[0])
          }
  });


  test('Should get auth for authenticated user', async () => {
    await agent
          .get('/api/auth/')
          .expect(200)
  });

}


module.exports = authtests;
```

I have double checked my DB is connected and user is correctly logged in. I have checked my cookies are set correctly. You can see this in the console log that is commented out. Yet the agent entering the auth route is empty (no cookies). Interestingly enough I have done exactly the same tests in the other app. Even more interestingly I have checked the code line by line and is identical. In the other app I have no such issue. Packages versions are also identical.

Thanks to anyone brighter then me that spots error I might be doing.

Comment: Maybe there is more than one `Set-Cookie` header? You ignore everything past the first one, currently.

Comment: CherryDT thanks for the help. No actually I have console log the cookie and it is specifically the one I need (and there is only one anyway).